# How to catch entitycollection inserts events in code?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an Entitycollection object "operations".
One property of this object is : "lines" (link to another table, one "operations" have multiple "lines").

I've add this :

```
public partial class operations
{
    public decimal total
    {
        get  {  return 0;}
    }
}
```

How can i raise a property changed on total when 
added an object in operations.lines ?

Comment: Well. Partial solution is to use an intermediate function to add objects :

public partial class operations
{
    public void addLigne(operations_lignes l)
    {
        this.lignes.Add(l);
        ReportPropertyChanged("total");
    }
}